# Why does Toast need Context?

Tags: android, android-context, android-toast

```
public static Toast makeText( Context context, int resId, int duration)
```

As in above code, `Context` is needed to make a `Toast`.
Explanation given by various resources is that `Context` is needed by the Toast class to be able to find and use the string’s resource ID. I am not able to understand why it is so. How does Context help in finding resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this part of the question

> How does Context help in finding resource ?

From the context [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html), context exists to access application specific resources

> Interface to global information about an application environment. ... It allows access to application-specific resources and classes,...

So the context class contains a [method](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29) `getResource()` which

> Return a Resources instance for your application's package.

Comment: Thanks to all for responses. So what I understand now is that every application has its own context which in turn is ONLY doorway to resources of that particular application. And there is no other way to access application's resources.

Answer (score 0):

The resource ids are context specific. Different applications have different contexts which means they may lead to different resources.